# How to customise AWS Textract?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, text-extraction, text-recognition, amazon-textract

So far my Textract tests are very impressive for handwriting, but I see sometimes it fails to recognise some forms and some values. Is it possible to train it? If I'm scanning the same type of form/document it will be very useful to amend the results and teaching it where the boundaries of some form elements lie and some key-value associations as well?

It will be a real deal breaker for the kind of service I'm trying to design.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to 'train' Amazon Textract.

The available actions are limited to analysing a document and detecting text.

See: [Actions - Amazon Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Operations.html)

Comment: Thanks You Sir. Is there any other options in AWS where In can create my own Textract and train it.

Comment: [Amazon SageMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/whatis.html) is a machine learning service where you can train models, but it's a very complex service and probably isn't what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I am working on a project to do exactly this.  You can look at this Hugging Face model and the referenced model in Github:
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/layoutlmv2

It isn't simple but it's the only open source solution I know of.

Comment: Thanks

Sure, I will check it out for.
@G. Casey